# Try to connect Sumo with OMNET++: Could not connect to TraCI server

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I've built a network of vehicles using sumo and I'm trying to connect these vehicles to an RSU using venis omnet++ but I'm getting this message:

> A runtime error occurred:
> Could not connect to TraCI server; error message: 111: Connection refused -- in module (veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) myTestNetwork.manager (id=6), at t=0s, event #1
> Launch a debugger with the following command?
> nemiver --attach=3256 &

I'm using omnet++ 5.6.2 and Venis 5.1 and sumo1.8.0
Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

I'm trying to check the host file to see if there's an error in the local address and I'm checking my firewall to see if there's a blocked port that's preventing me from connecting to the TraCI server.

Comment: Please also check whether there is an error in your sumocfg by trying to run the sumocfg without veins: `sumo -c my.sumocfg`